# How to copy the environment variables in cluster system using qsub?

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

I use the SUN's SGE to submit my jobs into a cluster system. The problem is how to let the 
computing machine find the environment variables in the host machine, or how to config the `qsub` script to make the computing machine load the environment variables in host machine?
The following is an script example, but it will say some errors, such as libraries not found:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    #$ -V
    #$ -cwd
    #$ -j y
    #$ -o /home/user/jobs_log/$JOB_ID.out
    #$ -e /home/user/jobs_log/$JOB_ID.err
    #$ -S /bin/bash
    #

    echo "Starting job: $SGE_TASK_ID"

    # Modify this to use the path to matlab for your system
    /home/user/Matlab/bin/matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -r matlab_job 

    echo "Done with job: $SGE_TASK_ID"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you are using (adding a -V) should work.  One possibility since you are specifying the shell with -S is that grid engine is configured to launch /bin/bash as a login shell and your profile scripts are stomping all over the environment you are trying to pass to the job.

Try using `qstat -xml -j` on the job while it is queued/running to see what environment variables grid engine is trying to pass to the job.

Try adding an `env` command to the script to see what variables are set.

Try adding `shopt -q login_shell;echo $?` in the script to tell you if it is being run as a login shell.

To list out shells that are configured as login shells in grid engine try:

```
SGE_SINGLE_LINE=true qconf -sconf|grep ^login_shells
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. I have solved this problem. I use `export` command to manually load the environment variables into the client machine. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is due to you didn't config BASH in the login_shells of SGE
check your login_shells by `qconf -sconf` and see if bash in there.

login_shells
       UNIX command interpreters like the Bourne-Shell (see sh(1)) or  the  C-
       Shell (see csh(1)) can be used by Grid Engine to start job scripts. The
       command interpreters can either be started as  login-shells  (i.e.  all
       system  and user default resource files like .login or .profile will be
       executed when the command interpreter is started  and  the  environment
       for  the  job will be set up as if the user has just logged in) or just
       for command execution (i.e. only shell  specific  resource  files  like
       .cshrc  will be executed and a minimal default environment is set up by
       Grid Engine - see qsub(1)).   The  parameter  login_shells  contains  a
       comma  separated  list  of  the  executable names of the command inter-
       preters to be started as login-shells.  Shells in this  list  are  only
       started  as  login shells if the parameter shell_start_mode (see above)
       is set to posix_compliant.

```
   Changes to login_shells will take immediate effect.   The  default  for
   login_shells is sh,csh,tcsh,ksh.

   This value is a global configuration parameter only. It cannot be over-
   written by the execution host local configuration.
```